# Unknown multi arch type

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, multiarch

When I run `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal, I got this and I don't know what the problem is:

```
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5akonadisearch-bin'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5akonadisearch-bin'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1404783